# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor from attempt to write a json file

Tags: python, json, file

I need to write a program with the scope of calculate and write in a JSON file some covid-19 statistics
I tried to write this:

```
import json
from json import JSONEncoder

f = open("contagi.json","a")
class contagi():
    def __init__(self , giorno , mese , anno , contagi_del_giorno):
        self.giorno = giorno
        self.mese = mese
        self.anno = anno
        self.x_contagi = contagi_del_giorno
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

y = contagi(18,10,2020,10095)

print(y.toJSON())

f.write(y.toJSON())
f.close()
```

but it gets this error:

```
>python contagi.py


{
    "anno": 2020,
    "giorno": 18,
    "mese": 10,
    "x_contagi": 10095
}
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giuse\Documents\json + python\contagi.py", line 20, in <module>
    f.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: The error message said error occurred when trying to close file. When close file, the OS also do flush operation to commit file to disk. So if your disk is full, the flush operation can fail and hence the error is reported.

Comment: Good question, but next time try to provide a [mre] :)